# ng-mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am at the very beginning of learning Angular. Right now I am trying to implement a ng-repeat div which is populated from a collection. I also want to implement a mouseOver function which changes the text in a paragraph when I hover over one of the elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

        app.controller('RezeptController', function ($scope) {
            this.rezepte = rezeptCollection;

            this.mouseOverElement = function (element) {
                this.msg = "Mouse Over: " + element.name;
            }

        });

        var rezeptCollection = [
            {name: 'Okroshka', herkunft: 'Russland'},
            {name: 'Sushi', herkunft: 'Japan'}
        ];

    </script>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="container" ng-controller="RezeptController as rezepte">
    <div ng-repeat="rezept in rezepte.rezepte" >
        <div ng-mouseover="mouseOverElement(element)">
            {{rezept.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does get the job of displaying the elements done. Unfortunately the mouseOverElement does not trigger.

I have to admit that I did not understand the scope concept entirly. So what I tried is to change the app.controller definition to:

```
        app.controller('RezeptController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.rezepte = rezeptCollection;

        $scope.mouseOverElement = function (element) {
            $scope.msg = "Mouse Over: " + element.name;
        }
    });
```

This does not fix the problem plus the items are not shown at all. Please help me understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue stem from the fact that you are using the `"RezeptController as rezepte"` notation, which is good practice, but then you are being inconsistent on how you access things in that scope.

You need to make sure you are prefixing any scope variable or function calls with `rezepte.` It is also good practice to take the confusion out of `this` by aliasing it as `rezepte` in your controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

        app.controller('RezeptController', function ($scope) {
            var rezepte = this;
            rezepte.rezepte = rezeptCollection;

            rezepte.mouseOverElement = function (element) {
                rezepte.msg = "Mouse Over: " + element.name;
            }

        });

        var rezeptCollection = [
            {name: 'Okroshka', herkunft: 'Russland'},
            {name: 'Sushi', herkunft: 'Japan'}
        ];

    </script>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="container" ng-controller="RezeptController as rezepte">
    <div ng-repeat="rezept in rezepte.rezepte" >
        <div ng-mouseover="rezepte.mouseOverElement(rezept)">
            {{rezept.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>{{ rezepte.msg }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I do it the way you suggested it still does not work. I tried to comment out the line: rezepte.msg = "Mouse Over: " + element.name; and put in an alert instead. It is being triggered. So the event is fired but the element is 'undefined'.

Comment: There is no such variable as `element`, pass in `rezept` instead. Edited answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
There are a few issues here:

1. You're passing `element` into the mouseover expression, but there is no such variable. Angular does make a `$event` object available, but it doesn't have access to that element's scope, so you'll need to play with it.
2. As mentioned elsewhere, you're using the `controllerAs` syntax, but then attempting to access variables assigned to the controller without indicating which controller you're accessing. This applies to your `msg` expression and your `mouseover` expression.
3. As I mention below, your `rezeptCollection` variable isn't available to the controller - declare and define it inside of the controller definition.

---

Your `RezeptCollection` variable is declared after your controller, so it won't be available within the controller. Declare that before the controller.

You're also not accessing scope when calling your mouseover function:

`<!-- which controller instance is this on? -->
<div ng-mouseover="mouseOverElement(element)">`

Try this:

`<!-- indicate a controller instance -->
<div ng-mouseover="rezept.mouseOverElement(element)">`

Comment: Won't the `RezeptCollection` variable definition be hoisted?

Comment: The variable declaration will be, but not the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in rezepte to the mouseOverElement function:

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="RezeptController as rezepte">
        <div ng-repeat="rezept in rezepte.rezepte" >
            <div ng-mouseover="mouseOverElement(rezepte)">
                {{rezept.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>{{ msg }}</p>
    </body>
```